# How do I evaluate the $(1,3)$-curvature tensor $R(X,Y)Z$ when $X,Y,Z$ are vector fields along a one-parameter family of curves?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian manifold and denote the space of smooth vector fields on $M$ by $\mathfrak{X}(M)$. Following Lee's book on Riemannian manifolds, we define the $(1,3)$-curvature tensor $R:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(M)$ by
$$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_Y Z-\nabla_Y\nabla_X Z-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z.$$
The definition of $R$ is as simple as it appears, before we introduce vector fields along a one-parameter family of curves.

Let $I,J$ be intervals in the real line. A one-parameter family of curves in $M$ is a map $\Gamma:J\times I\to M$, since it defines two collections of curves in $M$: the main curves $\Gamma_s(t):=\Gamma(s,t)$ and the transverse curves $\Gamma^{(t)}(s):=\Gamma(s,t)$. If $\Gamma$ is smooth, we denote the velocity vectors of the main and transverse curves by
$$\partial_t\Gamma(s_0,t_0)=\Gamma_{s_0}'(t_0)\text{ and }\partial_s\Gamma(s_0,t_0)=\Gamma^{(t_0)}\ '(s_0).$$
Each of these is an example of a vector field along $\Gamma$, which is a map $V:J\times I\to TM$ such that $V(s,t)\in T_{\Gamma(s,t)}M$ for each $(s,t)\in J\times I$. Now, there is a proposition that involves feeding $R$ with such vector fields.

> Proposition 7.5. *Suppose $(M,g)$ is a smooth Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $\Gamma:J\times I\to M$ is a smooth one-parameter family of curves in $M$. Then for every smooth vector field $V$ along $\Gamma$,
> $$D_s D_t V-D_t D_s V=R(\partial_s\Gamma,\partial_t\Gamma)V.\tag{7.5}$$*

I don't know what the RHS of (7.5) stands for: the input vector fields are not from $\mathfrak{X}(M)$. What am I supposed to do with it? Thank you.

**Note: For those who deem this question to be a duplicate, I know $R$ is a tensor field. Actually, after giving the definition of $R$, Lee showed in a proposition that $R$ is $C^\infty(M)$-linear in each argument and is thus induced by a $(1,3)$-tensor field.**

**Epilogue: For those who are struggling with the same question, my advisor told me it could be an abuse of notation. The author might have been implicitly using the pullback bundle $\Gamma^*(TM)$, a subtle agent that played an important role in the computation. The symbol $R$ here is actually the pullback of the original $(1,3)$-curvature tensor. For more information, please see [Pullback bundle - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle). Finally, I'd like thank all of the people who contributed an idea. Thank you.**

Comment: The Riemann curvature tensor is... A tensor! You can then evaluate it on tangent vectors

Comment: Thank you, but its definition clearly states that it can only take in **smooth vector fields on $M$**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic property of a tensor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468887/basic-property-of-a-tensor) (it is shown in Lee that $R$ is a tensor -that is, it's $C^\infty$-linear in each entries. Thus the value of the tensor depends only on the value of the vector at one point).

Comment: @Steve Yes, its definition states that entries are vector fields. But as ArcticChar suggested, it is a very basic property that $R$ is a tensor (just do the calculations). This fact is really important and very used in geometry: for example, the definition of sectional curvature is pointwise, and use the pointwise property of the Riemann tensor.

Comment: Thank you all, but what bothers me is not about how to show that $R$ is a tensor field. Instead, I don't see any possibilities that Lie brackets and covariant derivatives can be evaluated on tangent vectors. That's how it is.

Comment: @Steve We are not talking about evaluating Lie brackets and covariant derivatives on tangent vectors, but the whole Riemann curvature tensor $R$. It does not make sense for the two first but totally makes sense for the latter because it is a tensor. This is what is implicitely used for the equality you want to understand. It totally makes sense to take vectors as entries for $R$. That's all

Comment: @Didier Thank you. Are you suggesting I should use the $(1,3)$-tensor field $\mathfrak{R}$ that induces $R$, although we have been calling $R$ a tensor field?

Comment: If you fix $(s,t) \in I\times J$, $\partial_s\Gamma(s,t) = \Gamma_*\partial_s(s,t) \in T_{\Gamma(s,t)}M$ and similarly, $\partial_t\Gamma(s,t) \in T_{\Gamma(s,t)}M$. Also, $V(s,t) \in T_{\Gamma(s,t)}M$ Since $R$ is a tensor, $$R(\partial_s\Gamma(s,t),\partial_t\Gamma(s,t))V(s,t) \in T_{\Gamma(s,t)}M$$ is well defined. You need vector fields on $M$ to define $R$, but once it's defined, you just use it as a pointwise tensor and forget about vector fields.

Comment: This indeed can all be done using pullbacks of the bundle and connection, but you don’t need to know that.

Comment: Deane's comment is correct. The covariant derivative is NOT define for the vector field $V$ along $\Gamma$, because the covariant derivative depends LOCALLY on vector fields in $M$ (and pointwisely in the direction of derivation, so $\partial_s\Gamma$ and $\partial_t\Gamma$ impose no problems on the definition of the curvature) and could be no way at all to extend V to a neighborhood in $M$ in a way that the derivative is independent of the choice of extension. However, you prove that the curvature operator is a TENSOR, and tensors only depends POINTWISELY on its entries.